# How to redirect user to login page before using facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have created an app(canvas page) on facebook using PHP. I see that users without logging in to facebook can see the canvas page http://apps.facebook.com/svolzesocial

How to redirect user to facebook login page before using app?

For example, when we open Mashable Social reader, if the user is not logged into facebook he gets redirect to another facebook login page like as shown in image below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwceW.png

I want exactly like this only.

Answer (score 0):

Since your page is in a canvas app, you should be receiving a [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter posted to your server.  You should decode the request and determine if the user has already authenticated your app.  If the user has already allowed your app, just serve up the page they requested.  Otherwise you can just serve up a blank page that contains JavaScript call to redirect the user to the login screen.